# загрузка изображений через active admin в ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, model, gems

Я новичок в rails. Исходя из опыта с django лень было писать админку руками и я стал использовать active admin.Столкнулся с проблемой загрузки изображений.
1) Не знаю как указать путь загрузки 
2) не знаю как загрузить файл.
Заранее спасибо! 
вот мой код:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Imgpost do
permit_params :title, :image
 index do
    column :title
    column :image
    actions
  end

  filter :title

  form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
      f.inputs "Create new image post", :multipart => true do
        f.input :title
        f.input :image, :as => :file
      end
      f.actions 
  end
end`
```

Answer (score 2):

Для начала в описании не слова о `gems` для загрузки файлов. Если таковых действительно нет - можно воспользоваться этим `gem 'carrierwave'`. Документацию по нему можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

После его установки нужно выполнить команду `rails generate uploader MyUploader`

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  #тут указываем директорию в которую хотим загружать файлы
  def store_dir
    'public/my/upload/directory'
  end
end
```

Если картинку нужно загружать из админки - гем сам должен подружиться с такой формой, если из "клиентской части" - то в форму которая отвечает за билдинг объекта нужно добавить поле для загрузки файлов

```
 = form_for @object, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-4
      = f.file_field :image, html: {class: 'img-responsive'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с файлами существует гем Paperclip. Вот [ссыль](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) на его страницу.

Тогда в миграции примерно сл.: `t.attachment :jpg_products`
, а в модели:

```
has_attached_file :jpg_products,
                    :default_url => '/assets/no-photo.png',
                    :styles => { :original => "800x600!", :small => "268x198!" },
                    :default_style => :small,
                    :convert_options => {
                      :all => "-quality 85 -strip" }
```

в контроллере работаете с ним как с обычным полем.

Еще раз: [здесь](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) сам гем и подробная инструкция по настройке, установке..